# Customize Swagger Document Generation

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger

I Have a spring boot application with following config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.xxx.mypackages" })
public class MyWebAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

In my project I have some web services and spring controllers. I want swagger to be enabled only in my web service classes. Currently, it generates documentation for both rest and controller classes. How can I customize that?

I'm using following dependency in gradle.

```
compile "com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:1.0.2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [1.0.2 documentation](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/tree/v1.0.2#swaggerspringmvcplugin-xml-configuration) you'll find that `SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin` has a includePatterns method. This method takes a regular expression of the paths to include. For e.g. if you had an path prefix for the rest endpoints like this `/rest/some-resource....` you could include a pattern, something like the snippet shown below

```
@Bean
public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){
    return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
    //... more config goes here
          //regex to identify your rest services path
          .includePatterns(".*rest.*"); 
}
```

Also it would be useful to know that we're going to be [releasing 2.0](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/) shortly with support for [swagger spec 2.0](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md). That might be something to consider as well.